# cracklib-devel no longer available in CentOS 8

Tags: centos

I have installed epel-release in CentOS 8 docker image, but cracklib-devel is still unavailable:

```
No match for argument: cracklib-devel
Error: Unable to find a match: cracklib-devel
```

Does anyone know what's happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable EPL and [powertools repository](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL):

```
yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
dnf config-manager --set-enabled PowerTools
```

Then you will be able to install `cracklib-devel`.